# Djoser JWT endpoints Not able to use token endpoints

Tags: authentication, jwt, djoser

I have been using drf since a couple of months . For authentication I decided to use djoser package and use JWT token for better authentication. However whenever i try to use postman to send requests i can only send the three jwt requests. I'm wondering if i can use the Base endpoints as well such as re-setting the password and finding the user-
**Base Endpoints - https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/base_endpoints.html**
Not able to send requests. the error on postman always comes as "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
even if i apply the Bearer Token type in postman.
**can someone tell me how to use Base endpoints along with jwt ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use JWT with Djoser, send a Get request to

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/users/me

Instead of Bearer or Token, Set your Authorization header pass JWT as follows:

> Authorization: JWT ***your-JWT-access-token***

Here's a sample request using insomnia

```
> GET /auth/users/me/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
> Authorization: JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTk1MDYyNTcxLCJqdGkiOiI2NmZkODFkNDVlNmY0OTdlYWZiMGExZWE2YmRmZmM0MyIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjF9.uXZadgc_hYcS79tuZWet_4eDqNQlduKpcmD1a2JvfjY
```

if you had set up your urls correctly it will return your username, email and user-ID

Comment: Thank you so much .. solved the problem in no time . was using Bearer instead of JWT .. silly me :)